# User with no identity for the network where the question was migrated

Tags: support

I just found one user which (looks like) have no identity on SE. I found this question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/do-i-have-to-pay-taxes-as-international-student-in-canada-for-freelance-income migrated from http://travel.stackexchange.com

[image]

[image]

Actually, he has profile, here's the link, https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/20094/rana

I think this because he has not signed-up with expatriates network *therefor his profile name is looks like this*. If this is true? Ain't it important to show his (another network) profile where it exist. Or other possible way to show his identity on network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, this user's profile link / username is grayed out because he does not have an account on that particular Stack Exchange site. When a question gets migrated, a new user account is not created automatically on the migrated site. User has to signup on that SE site.

Is it important to show/link user's profile on the other SE site? I don't think so. Two reasons, on Stack Exchange sites emphasis is given to good questions and not to users. Secondly, the profile is two-clicks away anyways ('migrated from' banner takes you to original revision history and username takes you to the profile).

Comment: Good explanation @Aziz! Thanks! :)